# How to make console screen (Turbo C editor) full screen in MS-windows vista

Tags: c, editor

I creates program in c/c++ in turbo c . but i am facing problem is that i am not able to make it full screen in windows vista. please tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you still living in the Turbo era? Switch on to some better compiler.

gcc and MSVC++ Professional Edition are better ones.

On windows use IDEs like DevCpp or Code::Blocks, both support MinGw port of gcc.

Comment: can i create programs of c in MSVC++ studio?

Comment: is it that, which comes with Visual Studio (which we use for vb6.0)?

Comment: when we install vb6.0 their also comes editor for VC++. are u talking about that?

Comment: Visual C++(VC++) has integrated compiler, editor and debugger, use it and enjoy.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid, but you can't reliable switch to full-screen text mode anymore.

Microsoft deprecated support for full-screen text mode in the graphic drivers. It's optional now and some drivers still support it, but most manufacturers don't bother implementing a deprecated feature.

The best thing you can do is to open a real GUI window and emulate the text-mode display. Obviously this will not work with DOS programs.

---

Edit: If you can't life without full-screen you can always install DOSBOX. It will execute Dos programs and can emulate fullscreen for you. However, your programs will run slower because DOSBOX is basically a emulator and has it's own performance overhead.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use the new Express editions of Visual C++ 2008, it has an updated C++ compiler, which you can also use when trying to create C programs/apps. If you really wanna use Turbo compilers, you can set external tools on the Visual C++ 2008 Express, using the Turbo compilers as the external tools. That way you can compile your program with both MS C++ Compiler and your Turbo Compilers...